# Arrange records in such a way that D category always comes first then E & F will be in the ratio of 1:1

Tags: php, mysql

I want to arrange my records in such a way that D Category always comes first,then E and F will be in the ratio of 1:1 that means if E comes first then F comes after E and D will be on the top always,this sequence goes on.

Note- If some category comes more than one time then records with old date comes first as compare to another date of same category.

[image]

Note- AllocationID last 14 digits contains date and time.On the basis of allocationID date we look for same category records for arranging within the category.

My Query-

```
SELECT m.allocationID,mt.CatId,mt.CatSName,r.officerName,r.desgName,r.grade,r.cellNo,CASE 
                   WHEN mt.CatSName = 'D' THEN 0
                   WHEN mt.CatSName = 'E' THEN 1
                   ELSE 2
                   END as ord
                   FROM msttransaction m,msttemp mt,regusers r WHERE (m.isPending='Y' AND m.statusR='Approve' AND m.iscancelled='No' AND m.allocationID IN ( SELECT mt.AllocationId FROM msttemp WHERE mt.quarterId='082505012')and SUBSTRING(m.AllocationId,1,11)=r.pfNpsNo)  OR (m.isPending='N' AND m.type='Transit' AND m.statusR='Approve' AND m.iscancelled='No' AND m.allocationID IN ( SELECT mt.AllocationId FROM msttemp WHERE mt.quarterId='082505012')and SUBSTRING(m.AllocationId,1,11)=r.pfNpsNo) ORDER BY ord,SUBSTRING(m.AllocationId, -14)
```

Comment: Unclear what you want here.  Please edit your question and show, as _text_, clear sample input data and the expected output.  Don't use screen captures unless absolutely necessary (not the case here).

Comment: wait i will edit it

Comment: Please format the SQL code in a readable manner, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: for example, i have data like:d,d,e,e,f,e,f,e,d then it  should be display like as d,d,d,e,f,e,f,e,f,e,f in mysql query .

Comment: According to my query D comes first but  catch is i have to arrange E and F category alternate

Answer (score 1):

You can take a temporary variable on select clause, according to your category. 0 for all 'D' category.
Please look it my query. Hope it works for you.

**Example -**

```
SET @a := 0;
SET @b := 0;
SELECT *, IF((t1.cat = 'D'),0,IF(cat ='E', @a :=@a+1,@b :=@b+1)) as t
FROM (select * from `temp` ORDER BY cat ASC) as t1 
ORDER BY t ASC, cat ASC;
```

Comment: for example, i have data like:d,d,e,e,f,e,f,e,d then it should be display like as d,d,d,e,f,e,f,e,f,e,f in mysql query                                                                                                       According to my query D comes first but catch is i have to arrange E and F category alternate

Comment: @VAIBHAVRAWAT Please check above query again. I made some change on it.

Comment: please help me brother i am in big trouble,how to use your code i don't know how to write this code.this code is for stored procedure? i write a stored procedure what i got a error- #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4.please explain me i am very thankful to you.

Comment: my stored procedure is                                                                                                DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE db_quarters.PP5()
BEGIN

   SET @a:= 0;
   SET @b:= 0;   
    SELECT  
     EmpRemarkID
 ,EmpID
 ,EmpRemark    
    FROM
    (
 SELECT  
     EmpRemarkID
    ,EmpID
    ,EmpRemark
    ,IF((t1.cat = 'D'),0,IF(cat ='E', @a:=@a+1,@b:=@b+1)) as t
   FROM (select EmpRemarkID,EmpID,EmpRemark from db_quarters.empduplicate ORDER BY EmpID ASC) as t1 
      ORDER BY t ASC, EmpID ASC;       
 )
END $$
DELIMITER ;

Comment: `DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE db_quarters.PP5() 

BEGIN 
 SET @a:= 0; 
 SET @b:= 0; 
 SELECT t2.EmpRemarkID, t2.EmpID, t2.EmpRemark 
 FROM ( 
  SELECT t1.EmpRemarkID, t1.EmpID, t1.EmpRemark , IF((t1.cat = 'D'),0,IF(t1.cat ='E', @a:=@a+1,@b:=@b+1)) as t 
  FROM (
   select EmpRemarkID,EmpID,EmpRemark 
   from db_quarters.empduplicate 
   ORDER BY EmpID ASC) as t1
  ORDER BY t ASC, EmpID ASC ) as t2;
END$$ 
DELIMITER ;`

Comment: @VAIBHAVRAWAT Please check again. I have run this query without error.

Comment: @VAIBHAVRAWAT Fix?

Comment: Thanks Brother,According to your and some modification i got a sequence as i want D on top priority then E and F in the ratio 1:1 that means in alternate way like DDEFEFEF but there is another problem it will not short according to date within the category hope you understand what i want if not then i will explain more

Comment: this is my query

Comment: Add date column on 'order by' clause on 't1' table.
Like
ORDER BY EmpID ASC, date ASC) as t1

Comment: I am sending my query to you help me it does not take whole query in comments so i will give in two part

Comment: Set @a:=-1;
set @b:=0;
SELECT m.allocationID,mt.CatId,mt.CatSName,r.officerName,r.desgName,r.grade,r.cellNo,IF(mt.CatSName='E',@a:=@a+2,IF(mt.CatSName='D',0,@b:=@b+2)) as rwid
FROM msttransaction m,msttemp mt,regusers r WHERE (m.isPending='Y' AND m.statusR='Approve' AND m.iscancelled='No' AND m.allocationID IN ( SELECT mt.AllocationId FROM msttemp WHERE 

mt.quarterId='082505012')and SUBSTRING(m.AllocationId,1,11)=r.pfNpsNo)  OR (m.isPending='N' AND m.type='Transit' AND m.statusR='Approve' AND m.iscancelled='No' AND m.allocationID IN ( SELECT mt.AllocationId

Comment: FROM msttemp WHERE mt.quarterId='082505012')and SUBSTRING(m.AllocationId,1,11)=r.pfNpsNo) ORDER BY rwid,SUBSTRING(m.AllocationId,14)

Comment: Can u please share all related tables with some data. That help me to fix your issue.

Comment: can you share your email id,so i will give the whole logic and what i want as my output.Thanks in advance

Comment: Please give your email I will ping you.

Comment: vaibhav.rawat77@gmail.com